SHAP Additivity Check Fails with Astronomical SHAP Values for RandomForestClassifier
So I trained my model and here I can share some relevant parts regarding the issue:
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

# Load and preprocess data
news_df = pd.read_csv('../data/WELFake_Dataset.csv').fillna('')
news_df['clean_text'] = news_df['text'].apply(preprocess_text)

X = news_df['clean_text']
y = news_df['label']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Vectorizer
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', max_features=10000)
tfidf_train = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
tfidf_test = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(X_test)

# Model training with hyperparameter tuning
param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300],
    'max_depth': [None, 10, 20, 30],
    'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10],
    'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4],
    'bootstrap': [True, False]
}
rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(rf, param_distributions=param_grid, n_iter=20, cv=5, verbose=2, random_state=42, n_jobs=-1)
random_search.fit(tfidf_train, y_train)

best_rf_model = random_search.best_estimator_

# Save model and vectorizer
with open('../backend/tfidf_vectorizer.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(tfidf_vectorizer, f)
with open('../backend/best_rf_model.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(best_rf_model, f)

Now, I have a backend app where I try to use SHAP however I am getting a lot of issues and I decided to make a test file for it:
import pickle
import shap
import numpy as np
from utils.preprocessing import preprocess_text

# Load vectorizer and model
with open('../backend/tfidf_vectorizer.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    tfidf_vectorizer = pickle.load(f)
with open('../backend/best_rf_model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    classifier = pickle.load(f)

# Initialize SHAP Explainer
explainer_shap = shap.TreeExplainer(classifier)

# Sample text
sample_text = "The government has announced a new policy to combat fake news."
preprocessed_text = preprocess_text(sample_text)
feature_vector = tfidf_vectorizer.transform([preprocessed_text]).toarray()

# Predict
prediction = classifier.predict(feature_vector)[0]
proba = classifier.predict_proba(feature_vector)[0][1]

# Generate SHAP values
shap_values = explainer_shap.shap_values(feature_vector)
shap_values_positive = shap_values[1] if isinstance(shap_values, list) else shap_values

# Sum SHAP values
shap_sum = np.sum(shap_values_positive)
print(f"Sum of SHAP values: {shap_sum}")
print(f"Model output: {proba}")

# Additivity Check
if np.abs(shap_sum - proba) < 0.01:
    print("SHAP additivity check passed.")
else:
    print("SHAP additivity check failed.")

When I run the test file, I am getting this error:
python test_shap_consistency.py
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package wordnet to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package wordnet is already up-to-date!
SHAP version: 0.46.1.dev82
Classifier type: <class 'sklearn.ensemble._forest.RandomForestClassifier'>
Number of features in vectorizer: 10000
Number of features in model: 10000
Preprocessed text: government announced new policy combat fake news
Feature vector shape: (1, 10000)
First 10 features: [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
Prediction: Real
Probability of being Real: 0.9291109563602599
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usr\Desktop\tema\backend\test_shap_consistency.py", line 50, in <module>
    shap_values = explainer_shap.shap_values(feature_vector_dense)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\usr\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\shap\explainers\_tree.py", line 634, in shap_values
    self.assert_additivity(out, self.model.predict(X))
  File "C:\Users\usr\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\shap\explainers\_tree.py", line 816, in assert_additivity
    check_sum(self.expected_value[i] + phi[i].sum(-1), model_output[:, i])
  File "C:\Users\usr\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\shap\explainers\_tree.py", line 812, in check_sum
    raise ExplainerError(err_msg)
shap.utils._exceptions.ExplainerError: Additivity check failed in TreeExplainer! Please ensure the data matrix you passed to the explainer is the same shape that the model was trained on. If your data shape is correct then please report this on GitHub. Consider retrying with the feature_perturbation='interventional' option. This check failed because for one of the samples the sum of the SHAP values was -71537078264766386643956768191945774872434602891202492950066515140319945066393991267812782394642882616075517846114722773991424.000000, while the model output was 0.070889. If this difference is acceptable you can set check_additivity=False to disable this check.

What I tried:

Updated SHAP to version 0.46.
Ensured that both the TF-IDF vectorizer and Random Forest model have matching feature counts (10,000).
Verified that the preprocess_text function is consistent across all scripts.
Re-trained and re-saved the model and vectorizer to ensure integrity.
Checked for NaN and infinite values in SHAP values and feature vectors (none found).
Confirmed environment consistency by aligning library versions.
Does anyone have any idea what could the issue be.


You can't do anything about additivity check failure: it's not a version or your environment; it's model with some misbehaving figures. You either switch additivity check off or choose different model.

If you can complete a [mre] (provide a smaller/toy dataset that produces the same issue), it would help.  I wonder if it's just the very-sparse data?  Did you try feature_perturbation='interventional' as the error message suggests (although I would guess that may suffer from the sparsity as well)?
